# SBPL Lattice planner goal problem

Tags: ros, planner, sbpl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sometimes, when I set goal for the robot, the robot goes to the goal, but when it comes to goal, it is turning around himself (going in circle around himself). I suppose the problem is the resolution of error. How and where can i change that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/165881/sbpl-lattice-planner-goal-problem/) by [Ico](https://answers.ros.org/users/17981/ico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, If you fill that's the issue then, you can increase the value of goal tolerance in this file

navigation_experimental / sbpl_lattice_planner / launch / move_base / base_local_planner_params_close.yaml

Also try changing other parameters: [This tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup#Costmap_Configuration_.28local_costmap.29_.26_.28global_costmap.29) will help.

-Sudeep

---

Originally posted by [Sudeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/9671/sudeep/) with karma: 460 on 2014-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2